# Prove that a line can be found that divides the plane into $2$ parts, each of which contains exactly $n$ points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinations

On the plane for $2n$ distinct points. Prove that:

a) A line can be found that divides the plane into $2$ parts, each of which contains exactly $n$ points.

b) Assuming that no $3$ of the $2n$ points are collinear, prove that there exist at least $n$ lines passing through the $2$ points that divide the plane into $2$ parts, each containing exactly $n-1$ points.

Here all i did :

a) We proceed to connect all two points together. Since the number of points on the plane is finite, the number of line segments is finite. So we can find a line that is not parallel to all the given line segments. We call that line the line $d$.

Consider a coordinate system $Oxy$  whose vertical axis $ Oy$ coincides with the line $d$. Thus, the points on the plane will have distinct diaphragm degrees. Call those diaphragm degrees $ x_1,x_2,...,x_{2n}$ respectively. Proceed to choose the coordinate $m$ so that $x_1<x_2<...<x_n<m<...<x_{2n}$. So the line $y = m$ is the line to find.

But when it comes to the next part, I have no idea at all. I feel that if I deal with the problem like the previous part, I will get nowhere. I hope to get help from everyone. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the second part: try rotation rather than the translation of the first part

You might want to consider any particular point and the lines through it that connect to the other points ($2n-1$ of them since there is no collinearity and so are no duplicates).  Then consider each of these lines in turn by rotating round the particular point and what this does to the number of points on each side as you turn through half a circle to get back to your initial line but pointing in the opposite direction.

Once you have a line and pair of points, perhaps you can move on to another point not already paired and repeat